# I have setup a Kubernetes cluster on two EC-2 instances & dashboard but I'm not able to access the ui for the kubernetes dashboard on browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, kubernetes

I have setup a kubernetes(1.9) cluster on two ec-2 servers(ubuntu 16.04) and have installed a dashboard, the cluster is working fine and i get output when i do curl localhost:8001 on the master machine, but im not able to access the ui for the kubernetes dashboard on my laptops browser with masternode_public_ip:8001, [master-machine-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6dZX.png)
this is what my security group looks like [security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ezxK.png) which contains my machine ip.

Both the master and slave node are in ready state.

I know there are a lot of other ways to deploy an application on kubernetes cluster, however i want to explore this particular option for POC purpose.

I need to access the dashboard of the kubernetes UI and the nginx application which is deployed on this cluster.

So, my question: is it something else i need to add in my security group 
or its because i need to do some more things on my master machine?

Also, it would be great if someone could throw some light on private and public IP and which one could be used to access the application and how does these are related

Here is the screenshot of deployment details [describe deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9dP7.png) [2b][2c][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ha3X.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extensive topic ranging from Kubernetes Services (NodePort or LoadBalancer for this case) to Ingress Controllers and such. But there is a simple, quick and clean way to access your dashboard without all that.

Use either `kubectl proxy` or `kubectl port-forward` to access dashboard via embeded Kube apiserver proxy or directly forward from localhost to POD it self.

Comment: just now i figured it out that my application is running with the private IP

Comment: NOW HOW CAN I ACCESS THE DASHBOARD

Comment: as described on https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard - run `kubectl proxy` and access via URL like `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`

Comment: i ran kubectl proxy on the master server and it shows me the output on the CLI via putty but when i go to browser it cant access the UI as localhost wont work over there, i can see the dashboard is running on my ec2 server and it tells me that master is running at  https://172.31.23.173:6443 which is the private IP of my ec2 server ,and KubeDNS is running at https://172.31.23.173:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy  Now, My Question is how can i access it using private ip address as it is running with the private ip

Comment: you mean that http://localhost:8001 does not respond when you run `kubectl proxy` ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer 
Sorry for the delayed reply

I was trying to access the web application through its container's port but in kubernetes there is a concept of NodePort. so, if your container is running at port 8080 it will redirect it to a port between somewhere 30001 to 35000

all you need to do is add details to your deployment file 
and expose the service

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-svc
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    nodePort: 30001